# Problems importing "serial" in python

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm facing some problems with importing `serial` in my code. 
I'm using Python 3.7 and the latest version of pip (v20.2.3).

I have to say that I tryied also with the version 2.7 and 3.8 of Python, but no success.

Every time I try to import `serial` into my code I get this warning:

```
unresolved import 'serial'
```

Even thought I even uninstalled and reinstalled pip, python and serial.
Let me know if I missed any useful informations.

Comment: Please see the comments in this article. [ImportError: cannot import name Serial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63876172/9014308)

Comment: Maybe it's a vscode issue instead of python? [Pylint "unresolved import" error in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53939751/9014308), [Unresolved import in my django project : VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61412408/9014308), [visual studio code unresolved import?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57843117/9014308)